# Is there any way to write in my database located in the asset folder? or any other alternative way to handle such a condition?

Tags: android

I am tried to create an app that has a simple activity of login page and registration activity and I need to store the registration information in an external database in my asset folder and retrieve username and password while login the problem is that I can retrieve information from database but can't write in it?

Comment: I would call that an internal database. And yes, files in assets are read only.

Comment: I can't get what you trying to convey and I am a beginner so can you say it elaborately. And what is the other way to make my app work?

Comment: ??? I only confirmed what you said: a database in assets is not writable.

Comment: You cannot write files to assets folder. So if you are trying to use it for only saving registration info there are far better ways to do so.  Check account manager.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html
A more simple one shared preferences. 
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: If you wanna use your database file then first copy it to getFilesDir() or getDataBaseDir() and then use the copy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.